# AngularJs copy : does not placed in the second row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, array-push

I have a problem that I'm having a hard time with, I don't know how I can add into second row when I click the button using angularJS it always on the first row, sorry for my english.

Here's my template

```
     <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0px" ng-if="populateForm">
               
                    <div id="divGrid" class="dv well" ng-repeat="form in populateForm" ng-if="form.field_type == 'gridview'">

                        <div class="row clearfix">     
                          <div class="col-md-9"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-3" >
                               <button type="button"  ng-click="AddRow(form)" data="{{form.field_id}}"  id="AddBtn{{form.field_id}}" class="btn btn-success float-right btnCus"  >+</button>
                               <a  ng-click="removeRow($event)" id="RemBtn{{form.field_id}}" data="{{form.field_id}}" class="btn btn-warning float-right btnCus" ng-disabled="BtnDisable">-</a>
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive " style="padding: 0 3px;" id="parent{{form.field_id}}" >
                                <table class="table table-bordered"  border="" cellpadding="" cellspacing="" style="background-color:white" id="parent{{form.field_id}}">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr >
                                   <th ng-repeat="gridDColumn in form.GridList">{{gridDColumn.field_title}}</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                   <tbody>
                                     <tr>
                                     <td ng-repeat="gridData in form.GridList">
                             
                                     <div ng-if="gridData.field_type == 'Textbox' && gridData.field_datatype == 'Text'">
                                      <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'True'">
                                       <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                                          <div class="Textbox">
                                           <div ng-if="gridData.enable_textformat == 'True'">
                                           <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"   ng-model="gridData.value"   placeholder="{{gridData.field_textformat}}" type="text" ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == true"   class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                           </div>
                                            <div ng-else>
                                           <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"    ng-model="gridData.value"  type="text"  placeholder=""  ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == true"  class="{{gridData.field_required}} col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                           </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'False'">                               
                                          <div class="control-group">
                                          <div class="Textbox">
                                             <div ng-if="gridData.enable_textformat == 'True'">
                                                <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"  ng-model="gridData.value"   placeholder="{{gridData.field_textformat}}" type="text"  ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == false" class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                             </div>
                                               <div ng-else>
                                             <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"      ng-model="gridData.value"  type="text"  placeholder="" ng-required="{{gridData.field_required | lowercase}} && {{gridData.field_standard | lowercase}} == false" class="{{gridData.field_required}} col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                           </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div ng-if="gridData.field_type == 'Textbox' && gridData.field_datatype == 'Numbers'">
                                           <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'True'">
                                               <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                                                <div class="Textbox">
                                               <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"  ng-model="gridData.value"  placeholder="numbers" type="text"   class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control numbersonly"/>
                                               </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                               <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'False'">
                                               <div class="control-group">
                                                <div class="Textbox">
                                               <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"  ng-model="gridData.value"   placeholder="numbers" type="text"   class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control numbersonly"/>
                                               </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                            </div>
                                             <div ng-if="gridData.field_type == 'Textbox' && gridData.field_datatype == 'Date'">
                                              <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'True'">
                                               <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                                                <div class="Textbox">
                                               <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"  ng-model="gridData.value"  placeholder="numbers" type="text"  datepicker-popup='dd/MM/yyyy' datepicker-options='dateOptions' is-open='openedGrid'  class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                               </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                               <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'False'">
                                               <div class="control-group">
                                                <div class="Textbox">
                                               <input id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" name="textinput"  ng-model="gridData.value"   placeholder="numbers" type="text"  datepicker-popup='dd/MM/yyyy' datepicker-options='dateOptions' is-open='openedGrid'  class="col-md-5 rectangle form-control"/>
                                               </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                            </div>
                                              <div ng-if="gridData.field_type == 'dropdownList'">
                                          
                                              <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'True'">
                                               <div class="control-group has-feedback">
                                                <div class="dropdownList">                                           
                                                 <div  >
                                               <select id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" ng-model="gridData.value"  class="form-control"  ng-required="true" >
                                                 <option value="" >(Select)</option>
                                              <option ng-repeat="dd in gridData.Newvalue" ng-value="dd.dd_value">
                                             {{dd.dd_text}}
                                               </option>
                                           </select>
                                                 </div>             
                                               </div>
                                             </div>
                                           </div>
                                               <div ng-if="gridData.field_required == 'False'">
                                               <div class="control-group">
                                                <div class="dropdownList">
                                                 <div >
                                                    <select id="sub{{gridData.field_id }}" ng-model="gridData.value"  class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="" >(Select)</option>
                                        <option ng-repeat="dd in gridData.Newvalue" ng-value="dd.dd_value">
                                        {{dd.dd_text}}
                                        </option>
                                     </select>
                                                 </div>
                                             
                                               </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                            </div>
                                              <div ng-if="gridData.field_type == 'Checkbox'">
                                               <div class="Checkbox">
                                               <label id="sub{{gridData.field_id }} checkbox" style="font-weight:lighter;" >
                                               <label style="margin-left:-20px;display:none;"> {{gridData.field_desc}}</label>
                                                </br><input id="{{gridData.field_id }}" type='checkbox' class=" gridData.field_required "> 
                                               </label>
                                               </div>
                                               </div>
                                          </td>
                                      </tr>

                                  
                                   </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>                              
                     </div>   
                                     
                    </div>
```

My controller

```
     $scope.AddRow = function (obj) {

                    var se = obj.GridList;
                    var appendValue = "";
                    $scope.counter = 0;
                    angular.forEach(se, function (vals) {

                        var _dat = angular.copy(vals);

                        console.log(vals);


                        se.push(_dat);
                    })
                    }
```

Example screenshot 1 when button copy is not click.
[not click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEr3i.png)
When button is clicked screenshot 2.
[output clicked button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFCC9.png)
I'm beginner I don't know what exactly todo here it always place on the first row not on the second row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.AddRow = function (obj) {
    var gridData = obj.GridList;
    var appendValue = "";
    $scope.counter = 0;
    var last_row = _.last(gridData);
    console.log(last_row);
    if (last_row) {
        gridData.push(last_row);
    } else {
        gridData.push({
            title: null,
            name: null,
        });
    }
}
```

Use Underscorejs and get the last row and push directly without for each loop.
https://underscorejs.org/#last

Comment: yeah it's working for me but the problem here is when button is clicked they went to the "1st row check the image above" not in the 2nd row of table.

Comment: are you adding ng-repeat in td add in tr so this one not happens.

Comment: <td ng-repeat="gridData in form.GridList"> replace in <tr ng-repeat="gridData in form.GridList"> and checked